Does every oriented $3$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$ bound an oriented $4$-dimensional submanifold?
In my recent research, I encountered the following problem about embeddings. Let $M^3$ be a closed compact oriented smooth $3$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$. Does there exist a compact oriented smooth $4$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$, denoted by $N^4,$ such that $\partial N=M.$ Both $M$ and $N$ are allowed to have multiple connected components.
To my limited knowledge, if we go up one dimension, then the answer is yes. In other words, every closed $3$-dimensional submanifold $M$ does bound a $4$-dimensional submanifold $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^7$. To see this, since every closed $3$-manifold is a boundary, we have a smooth $4$-manifold $N'$ with boundary $M.$ By Whitney's embedding theorem for manifold with boundaries, $N'$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^7.$ By the Whitney-Wu unknotting theorem, any two embeddings of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^7$ are ambient isotopic. Thus we know $N'$ can be embedded into  $\mathbb{R}^7$ with the submanifold $M$ as the prescribed boundary.
Even though the reasoning in the previous paragraph already seems like an overkill, I don't know how to proceed further. Neither do I have success in finding counterexamples, as it seems all spheres are unknotted in codimension at least $3$.
I'm sorry if my question is trivial, as I work in geometric measure theory, thus very far from differential topology. Thank you so much for your help and understanding.
Added: colleagues have pointed out in the comments below that if we go down one dimension the statement also holds. In other words, every closed oriented $3$-dimensional submanifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$ bounds a $4$-dimensional oriented submanifold $N$. The proof also appears in Kirby's book. Thus, we know that $3$-dimensional closed oriented submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^k$ always bound $4$-dimensional oriented submanifolds if $k\not=6.$ Hopefully, this makes the case of $k=6$ a little more interesting.
Addendum: colleagues have pointed out in the comments that the case of $M$ connected is proven in Section 3 of Skopenkov's work. Thus, the only part unknown is what happens when $M$ has more than one connected component.

You might want to have a look at Chapter VI "Immersing 4-manifolds in R^6" of Rob Kirby's "The topology of 4-manifolds" (LNM 1374).  The statements in that chapter don't solve your problem, but the techniques might.

It's a long shot, but when $M$ is connected you can also try this strategy (used for proving that codim-2 submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ bound). Call $E$ the exterior of $M$. First, prove something about the normal bundle of the embedding (like that it's trivial, or at least has a section—here you probably need to use that $M$ is a 3-manifold, hence parallelisable) and then use the fact that $\mathbb{Z} \cong H_2(E) \cong [E,\mathbb{CP}^\infty]$. [...]

Now pick a generator $f\colon E \to \mathbb{CP}^\infty$ of $H_2(E)$ (under this identification) and use cellular approximation to reduce to actually look at a map $g\colon E \to \mathbb{CP}^2$. The preimage of a generic sphere generating $H_2(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ might do the trick. (Care needs to be taken at the boundary of $E$, among other places.)

Thank you for your detailed comments! I'll add these to the question as well

There is an obstruction to your manifold $M$ embedding in $\mathbb R^5$, but off the top of my head I don't see why it should be an obstruction to being the boundary of an embedded submanifold.  But it might be.

Maybe the reduction mod 2 of this obstruction to embedding in $\mathbb R^5$ is an embedded cobordism invariant.

Zhenhua, you have spent over a year now posting lovely questions in topology! I think you should no longer fear that your questions are trivial.

For $M$ connected, this appears to be true (start of Section 3 here). For $M$ a connected homology sphere, there's a nice argument (Section 2 here) which is similar to your $k=7$ argument: embed $N$ with $\partial N = M$ in $S^6$ using the result in Kirby's book. It turns out that you can embed $N \setminus D^4_+$ such that its boundary $M \setminus D^3$ agrees with the restriction of any given embedding $M \hookrightarrow S^6$. [...]

[...] The embedding of the cut out $D^3$ can be arranged to agree with the restriction of some embedding of $S^3$ into $S^6 \setminus M$. Your question is answered for $S^3 \hookrightarrow S^6$ here, so we have an embedding $V^4 \hookrightarrow S^6$ extending the embedding of $S^3$. Our desired embedding is then the boundary connected sum $M ,\natural, V$.

@mme
Many thanks for your encouragement! It means a lot to me.

To other colleagues, many thanks for your detailed comments! I'll add them to the prompt as well.

As pointed out, it suffices to deal with the non-connected case. But the non-connected case can be reduced to the connected case by geometrically forming the connected sum of the components within the ambient manifold (euclidean 6-space in our situation) as follows. First choose disjoint paths in the ambient manifold connecting the connected components of $M$. Then thicken these paths to 4-dimensional closed handle bodies of the form (closed interval) times (closed 3-ball). Finally add the boundaries of the handle bodies to $M$ and then remove the interior of the intersection of $M$ with the handle bodies to form a connected manifold $M'$ (round the corners if needed). It is clear that $M'$ is a model of the connected sum of components of $M$. Now if $M'$ bounds a 4-fold $N'$ in the ambient, then we can arrange $N'$ by a general position argument to avoid the handle bodies; there is sufficient room for this arrangement because the handle bodies are essentially one-dimensional. Then the union of $N'$ with the closed handle bodies is a 4-fold $N$ whose boundary is $M$.
